# how to config the db2 odbc driver 32 bit(i need to write 32 bit programe) in Windows 64

Tags: windows, db2, odbc, 64-bit, 32-bit

1. install the 64 bit db2 odbc on win10 64bit ,it work well
2. install the 32 bit db2 odbc on win7 32bit , it work well
3. but i try to many time, 32 bit db2 odbc on win10 64bit, i use the 32bit odbc manager, it not work, just not responding...
   [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPUKx.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXHDg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjE14.png)

i try to install odbc_cli.zip and odbc_rtcl.exe , and it produce the same effect.

how to config 32bit db2 odbc driver in windows 64bit?

Comment: The image shows a success message. Please edit your question to be more clear, what exactly is not responding?  When using the 32-bit clidriver, it is important that the PATH for the executable has the 32-bit libraries (dlls) coming before any 64-bit path.  Did you study the documentation how to configure the `db2dsdriver.cfg` XML file either with a text editor or by special command lines?

Comment: i m sorry. the pic shows the success of 64bit dirver of 64bit windows. i lost a pic for the fail of 32bit driver of not responding.  i just copy the content of db2dsdriver.cfg from some blogs.  can you give me some examples?

Comment: the cfg file content：
<configuration>
<databases>
<database name=”dbTest” host="XXXXXX" port=”50000″>
<parameter name=”CurrentSchema” value=”dbTest”/>
<wlb>
<parameter name=”enableWLB” value=”true”/>
<parameter name=”maxTransports” value=”50″/>
</wlb>
<acr>
<parameter name=”enableACR” value=”true”/>
</acr>
</database>
</databases>
<parameters>
<parameter name=”GlobalParam” value=”Value”/>
</parameters>
</configuration>

Comment: Do not use comments to add facts, because comments are not searchable. Instead, EDIT your question.  Do study the docs. After unzipping clidriver, ensure you run `db2cli install -setup` for both 32-bit and 64-bit clidrivers. When you want to use the 32-bit clidriver in your program, verify that its bin directory appears on the PATH before the 64-bit version. `db2dsdriver.cfg` is optional, use the free online Db2 Knowledge Centre to study all the information about it including examples. Just search `db2dsdriver.cfg` here https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5